# JPA/Hibernate: on delete set null

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa, mapping

So I've already noticed there is no easy solution to use `on delete set null` with JPA, but I heard there may be workarounds.
My problem is the next (it's getting a bit abstract here, but I hope it still makes sense):

Imagine there are **employees**. Every employee knows their **boss**, but not the other way around. Bosses are employees themselves.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

If a boss gets fired, everybody who worked under him will lose his boss (obviously).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee
{
 @Column (name = "id" )
 private String id;

 @OneToOne
 @JoinColumn( name = "boss" )
 private employee boss;
}
```

This is how it worked in SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE
ADD CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINTNAME FOREIGN KEY (BOSS)
REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (ID)
ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

I don't want people without a boss to get fired as well, I just want them to lose their reference to their former boss.
I saw solutions using @PreRemove but I am unsure if this does the same as I intend to.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes `@PreRemove()` is a good way to go.
But you need to have the bidirectional association on the inverse side, meaning `Employee` should have a `@OneToMany` with `Employee` (employees under supervision). And then add this method in `Employee`:

```
@PreRemove
private void removeAssociationsWithChilds() {
   for (Employee e : employees) {
        e.setBoss(null);
   }
}
```

But, if you don't want to keep track on the inverse side, meaning if you don't want to have a list of employees under supervision by the boss using `@OneToMany`, then you will have to do it manually via HQL just before deletion, such as `update Employee e set e.boss = null where e.boss = ?`, and then delete the boss.

Comment: Actually I use a @OneToOne association, forgot to add that. how would it look then?

Comment: Almost same, just that you need to have a `@OneToOne` instead of `@oneToMany`, and then on `removeAssociationsWithChilds(){ employeeUnderSupervision.setBoss(null) }`

Comment: The boss has at most one `Employee` under supervision, so it can be listed as a single attribute `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "boss") private Employee employeeUnderSupervision;` that's why `removeAssociationsWithChilds(){ employeeUnderSupervision.setBoss(null); }`

Comment: My problem right now (maybe just a question of understanding)
The employee I am holding at the moment is the boss. The boss doesn't know any employee who is refering to him as his boss. I can just access the boss of the boss.

Comment: That's why I mentioned bidirectional relationships. With them, the employee(owner side), keeps a reference to the boss. The boss(inverse side) also keeps a reference to the employee under supervision(this reference makes the relationship bidirectional, and it's optional but useful). If you don't want to use bidirectional relationships then you will have to use the HQL query approach.